# Kafka: ERROR Shutdown broker because all log dirs in E:\kafka\data\kafka have failed (kafka.log.LogManager)

Tags: apache-kafka

I searched for solutions to this problem but there are only temporary fixes for this like changing the log dirs location in server.properties. The error creeps on you after some days.
My application runs continuously, so are there any permanent fixes for this?

Comment: A "fix" probably would require moving to a Linux server, where Kafka is more robustly tested

Comment: I wish I could, but my application is a Windows application. I am using Unreal Engine.

Comment: You cannot use WSL2?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't reply faster, I will try WSL2. Do you know what is the reason for this error?

Comment: "log dirs have failed" could indicate permissions or a failing hard drive. Hard to know

Answer (score 0):

Existing bug reports about this issue since 2018 are not being addressed by Apache Kafka because the product is not officially supported on Windows. Only Linux etc. are supported.
According to users in this bug report, the problem is caused by the way windows handles file deletion (deleting files that are still open for writing is not allowed by the OS, wich is no problem on linux).

During the cleaning of the logging (default every 168 hours is 7 days) this causes a crash.

A fix was made by prehistoric-penguin and provided in a [pull request # 6403](https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/6403), but this fix is never accepted by Apache Kafka as mentioned above

Possible solutions/workarounds:

1. Start running the Kafka cluster as a linux machine
2. Using the fork of prehistoric-penguin for an update of your Kafka including the fix. (not tried myself)
3. Change the retention settings in such a way that it occurs less often.
4. Somehow automatically stop Kafka in the weekends after stop all clients, delete logs of Kafka and Zookeeper and build it all up again.

The settings are at \config\server.properties log.retention.hours = 168